# How to differentiate between test and live websites without changing back-end?

Tags: testing, browser

We have an issue where we have a website for test and an equivalent website for live. What we are finding is that due to carelessness our testers are using the wrong site (e.g. testing on the live site!).

We have total control over both sites, but since the test site is for acceptance testing by the users we don't want to make them different in any way. The sites must look the same and there is also a layer of management that will kick up a storm if the test and live sites are in any way different.

How have other people solved this problem? I am thinking of a browser plugin to make the browser look different somehow (e.g. changing the colour of the location bar when on the test website). Does anyone know of a plugin or a technique that would work? (We primarily use Firefox and Chrome)

Thanks,

Phil

**UPDATE**

We eventually settled on a program of: different credentials for the test and live site (this was not popular!) and making a series of plugins available for those who wanted them (colourize tabs for Chrome and Firefox users - we never did find a good plugin for IE).

Thanks to those who answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our company we use different site's names:

- www.dev.site.com - for developers
- www.qa.site.com - for QA's
- www.site.com - production site

Another good practic is to use different users credentials for dev\qa and prod sites.

Comment: Yes, the websites are deployed on very different addresses. The issue is that it is easy to click on the wrong bookmark / shortcut and accidentally go to the wrong site. If you don't check your URL bar you will not notice the mistake. I have seen a number of our testers do this!

Comment: However I do like your idea about using different credentials! This would certainly help alert the tester that they are using the wrong site.

Comment: "Tick" for the advice on using different credentials.